# Draggable object with multiple boundaries

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have my player dragged around the stage. If the player hits any object(All perfect rectangles) that I lay out in a movieclip, I'd like the player to hit a wall and stop moving. What's the most efficient way to  write this?

Do I loop through all the points the player can't hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built in methods for hit testing, you loop through all the objects you want to hit test against (make each it's own sprite or hit test the entire sprite that contains all the parts against the object depending on what kinds of info you want to have.  You may also want to rig up your own custom Sprite that has hit regions for the left right top and bottom to determine which edge the player has hit.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()

[Multiple hittest AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838939/multiple-hittest-as3)

Comment: But I've had issues with it getting stuck on objects. I could try again.

Comment: well if you are hitting the object you'll need to move it so that it's no longer hitting otherwise the condition that checks if it's a hit will just continue to return true, you have to be sure you still allow for the position to be changed